# probability that the system is deemed functional

Tags: probability

### Question

> The security system at an IT office is composed of $10$ computers of which exactly four are working. To check whether the system is functional, the officials inspect four of the computers picked at random (without replacement). The system is deemed functional if at least three of the four computers inspected are working. Let the probability that the system is deemed functional be denoted by $p$. Then $100p=$

### My Approach

I Know that this questio can be solved by -:

$P \text{(Atleast 3 working=All four working +3 working and 1 not working}$

$$\frac{1}{\binom{10}{4}}+\frac{\binom{4}{3} \times \binom{6}{1}}{\binom{10}{4}}$$

But i have doubt in another approach ,using [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

$P(\text{working})=\frac{4}{10}$

$P \text{(Atleast 3 working)=All four working +3 working and 1 not working}$

$$=\binom{10}{3} \times (\frac{4}{10})^{3} \times (\frac{6}{10})^{7}+\binom{10}{4} \times (\frac{4}{10})^{4} \times (\frac{6}{10})^{6}$$

In both case i am getting different answer .Why ?
Please help.I am totally stucked

Comment: please help me out

Answer (score 0):

The probability of having a working computer is $p=0.4$.

The experiment of the problem indeed follows the ***Binomial Distribution***, as we want to express the number of successes ($3$ working computers) in $4$ trials.

The p.d.f. of the Binomial Distribution for our specific experiment, is :

$$\mathbb{P}(p|n,k)=\binom{n}{k}(1-0.4)^{n-k}\cdot 0.4^k = \binom{n}{k}0.6^{n-k}\cdot 0.4^k$$

Now as mentioned, we want $3$ successes in $4$ trials, thus $n=4$ and $k=3$ and :

$$\mathbb{P}(p=0.4|n=4,k=3)=\binom{4}{3}0.6^{4-3}\cdot0.4^3$$

Comment: So the answer should be $=\binom{4}{3} \times (.4)^3 \times (.6)^{1}+\binom{4}{4} \times (.4)^4 \times (.6)^{0}=0.1536+0.0256=0.1792$ But the answer is $0.119$

Answer (score 0):

The binomial distribution could be used if computers where selected **with replacement**. Without replacement you have to use the hypergeometric distribution, and you obtain the same result you mention.